# change icon tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am new in React and semantic view. 
I have a Table which has a row that showing ok and a green checkmark is `{this.props.email.success}` return true. otherwise its change to red remove icon.
here is my code :
semantic-ui code :

```
<Table.Cell>
  <Icon color="green" name="checkmark" size="large" />
  {this.props.email.success}
</Table.Cell>
```

now based on success value the `Icon` `name` and `color` should change.
how can I do this ? 
thank for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
<Icon color={this.props.email.success ? "green" : "red"} name="checkmark" size="large" />
```

**EDIT**

Credit to @D Lowther If you want to change more than just the color of the icon you could do something like this:

```
let icon = (this.props.email.success) ? <Icon color...> : <Icon color...>;
return (<Table.cell>{icon}</Table.cell>);
```

Comment: Although it sounds like the else is another icon so maybe more like:
`let icon = (this.props.email.success) ? <Icon color...> : <Icon color...>;
<Table.cell>{icon}</Table.cell>`
or maybe create an icon object with a color and name property and build the conditional to fill its values.

Comment: Well, I don't know what `success` is but I guess its of type boolean. Yeah you could create two objects (one for success and one for failed), but this should usually work and is the cleanest way i can imagine

Comment: Sorry, your way is clean I was saying it sounded like from the question that they actually needed a different icon entirely not just the color. On further thought I would probably lean towards creating an object and using that to fill the Icon element based on the boolean response.

Comment: @DLowther Yeah I got what you were trying to say. Edited my answer to include your idea ;)